# Inequality Problem $\forall A , B,N>0\exists C>0:Cn^4\geq An^3 + Bn^2 + N$

Tags: analysis

Okj guys I need some Tipps with this one. Tried it with Induction, but just cannot figure it out

$\forall A , B,N>0\exists C>0:Cn^4\geq An^3 + Bn^2 + N$
(C has to be independent from n)

Comment: for enough great n, C=1 works.

Comment: I got that but i dont know how to continue that it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Given $A,B,N>0$,

we have

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^4}{An^3+Bn^2+N}=+\infty$ thus for enough great $n$, we will have

$\frac{n^4}{An^3+Bn^2+N}>1$ for example.

so, we can take $C=1$.
there are many possibilities.

Comment: I see it must be true only problem is we havent introduced the limit yet, so we are not allowed to use it

Answer (score 0):

for $A,B,N>0$ and $n \geq 1$, we have

$An^3\leq An^4$

$Bn^2\leq Bn^4$

$N \leq Nn^4$

so
$An^3+Bn^2+N \leq (A+B+N)n^4$

thus, we can take

$C=A+B+N$.